# Question regarding Evan's proof of Global Approximation by $C^∞(\overline{U})$ functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

[The page where the proof is is on Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA268#v=onepage&q&f=false). [A picture of the statement and the proof.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbRCh.jpg) I roughly paraphrase the statement of the result (this is Theorem 3 of Section 5.3.3, page 252-253 in the first edition, 266-267 in the second edition):

> Suppose $U$ is bounded with $C^1$ boundary, and $u∈ W^{k,p}(U)$. Then there are $C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$ functions $u_n$ such that $‖u_n - u‖_{W^{k,p}} → 0$.

I'm quite sure I understand the proof but I am left a little anxious over the choice to use $r/2$ instead of $r$ when 'moving within $U$ to make space for mollification', and later $r_i/2$ when patching things up with a partition of unity. Can someone shed some light on this? Or does the proof work without using this smaller ball?

Comment: The link is broken. At least I cannot read it.

Comment: @Jack My apologies for the late reply; upon reading it again I understand the proof and the choice of r/2. (or anything less than r will do). I will update the question with a picture and give a short answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V=B_{r/2}(x^0) ∩U$; Note that $\bigcup_{v∈ V}[ B_{ε}(v)+2ε e_1 ]$ is pushed up from $\partial U$ by about $ε$. The choice of $r/2$ stops this set from 'spilling out' of $B_r$. A (hopefully) convincing sketch:

[image]