# Evan's proof of approximation by smooth functions up to the boundary of Sobolev functions

Tags: proof-explanation

My question: Why is the function $f_\epsilon$ continuous (smooth) up to the boundary?

This is theorem 4.3 in the new edition of Evans & Gariepy's "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of functions."

I understand the proof and constructions. However I have difficulty seeing why the function $f_\epsilon$ is continuous (smooth) up to the boundary -- which is the whole point of the theorem as otherwise this theorem would have nothing more than an earlier theorem claiming approximation by $C^\infty(U)$ functions.

The following question was asked about the same proof, in case it helps:

[Question regarding Evan's proof of Global Approximation by $C^∞(\overline{U})$ functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729397/question-regarding-evans-proof-of-global-approximation-by-c%e2%88%9e-overlineu-f)